# File drag and drop not working on listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, drag-and-drop, listbox

This is the first time I am working with drag and drop. So I have a form with a `listbox` and nothing else. I would like to be able to drag and drop files from desktop or windows explorer into my listbox. This is my code. What is missing?

**Form:**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }


        private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                listBox1.Items.Add(s[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Form1.Designer.cs: (InitializeComponents)**

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // listBox1
    // 
    this.listBox1.AllowDrop = true;
    this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 23);
    this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
    this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(376, 238);
    this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.listBox1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragDrop);
    this.listBox1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragEnter);
    this.listBox1.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragOver);
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(438, 366);
    this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Comment: what you have in DragOver event?

Comment: Be specific about the effect you want, only DragDropEffects.Copy makes sense.  And remove the DragOver event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant I want the name of the file be added to my listbox. I have also removed the `DragOver`event handler.

Comment: Well, what does the debugger tell you?  If you don't get the DragEnter event at all then you need to run Visual Studio without elevation.

Comment: @HansPassant you mean not to run it as administrator? Because I am currently running Visual Studio as an admin.

Comment: Windows doesn't permit drag+drop from a non-elevated to an elevated app.  UIPI forbids it, the lesser known aspect of UAC.

Comment: @HansPassant it worked when I ran it using the `.exe` file from the debug folder! So when I am running VS as Admin, I am elevated and when I drag something into my program from the desktop, it's a non-elevated user who is doing it and therefore it is not allowed? What should I do to change that? Stop running VS as admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make this and i think this will be OK.And no need DragOver.

```
    private void listBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void listBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
        }
        string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            listBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s[i]));
    }
```

Comment: nothing has changed. And I still get a "not allowed" icon when I drag a file into the `listbox`.

Comment: should my form also has its `AllowDrop` option set to `true`?

Comment: AllowDrop is true. I found one thing, some icon like Recycle Bin cannot do.

Comment: trust me I am not dragging my recycle bin there ;) it is `.png` and `.csv` files.

Comment: Check this.. :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nhcn9zk4oydpo4/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip?dl=0

Comment: this does not work either! I am dragging files from my desktop. Do they only work in `release` mode?

Comment: oh! it works when I run the `.exe` file from the debug folder but not when I run it via the IDE. I am running visual studio as an administrator. Is that the reason?

Comment: I don't think so, but I am not sure.